# How is the Order By working in this query

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

```
SELECT * FROM TT 
ORDER BY (SELECT AGE 
          FROM TTT 
          WHERE NAME='TANDEL'
          );
```

Result is,

```
JOHN    2
PRAVEEN 2
KUMAR   2
RAKESH  2
WASIB   2
GURUNG  2
DAYALAN 5
DEEPAK  2
TANDEL  5
RAGHU   5
GIGA    5
DEEPA   5
DEVARAJ 2
```

Note: Table TT and TTT both have same data.

Answer (score 4):

Quite simply, it's not working. Order By requires a column or columns, if random data is passed into it instead of column names, it does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Order By requires a column or some columns

[ORDER BY CLAUSE](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/order_by.php)

```
SELECT * 
FROM TT 
ORDER BY colname
```

Answer (score 0):

In the order by clause we can add two thing:

- Column names

  ```
  Select * from TTT order by age;
  ```
- Coulmn number to filter

  ```
  Select * from TTT order by 2;//if age is the second column in the table 
              or
  Select name,age from TTT order by 2; // this will order by age
  ```

In the following case the inner query

```
  SELECT AGE 
      FROM TTT 
      WHERE NAME='TANDEL'
```

will return 5

and the parent query

```
  SELECT * FROM TT 
   ORDER BY 5
```